# Is it possible to have a custom Name below the firebase key?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to have a custom Name below the firebase key? You usually setup your firebase stuff by having one custom name along with a value. Ex (food1:Sandwich). Is it possible to customize it by making "food1" an input value just like "Sancwich"?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem you're trying to solve here. Can you edit your question show the database structure you have, and the code that created that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking to have the property name come from a variable.

So if you have this for a fixed name:

```
ref.set({ food1: "Sandwich" })
```

Then `food1` is a symbol and not a variable.

---

If you want `food1` to be the value of a variable, you can do:

```
let name = "food1";
ref.set({ [name]: "Sandwich" })
```

The `[name]` here is a special notation that ensures it uses the *value* of the `name` variable instead of `"name"` itself.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, close enough to `${}`, thanks :)